# Is there a way to 'update' and see changes to an appended object?

Tags: modeling, append

The situation I have is that there is a blender file called scene1.blend which contains an appended object called box.blend. I have made some changes to box.blend, how do I see those changes in the appended version in scene1.blend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reuse existing materials, objects, etc from an existing .blend?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend)

Comment: If version of box.blend was [appended and not linked](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/linked_libraries.html#append-and-link) then no way to see other than relinking into scene1.blend.

Comment: save the scene1 blend then go to *File* > *Revert*. That will reload the file updating any linked objects.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you describe, I think you're looking for *Link*, not *Append*.

Link, allows you to have the same object in two or more documents. Being linked, if you make changes to the original the same changes will happen in every linked document too. For this reason, you can't edit a linked object, you can only edit the original whereas Append creates a duplicate of the object.

Reload Linked files by going to the *Blender File* in the *Outliner* editor type, <kbd>Right-clicking</kbd> the linked file, and *select Reload*, Shortcut <kbd>E</kbd> .