# Material libraries in Blender 2.8 for Eevee

Tags: materials, blend-files, append

Helo everyone! Is there any way to make or create a material library in the last version of blender (2.8)? 
I just figurate out how to append the materials into a new file but would b super cool if I  could collect all of them in a typical library, as key shot can have. 
If you have found a tutorial or a way go ahead and send it to me!
Thank you very much in advance!
Nerea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reuse existing materials, objects, etc from an existing .blend?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend)

Answer (score 2):

Now, there is [BlenderKit](https://www.blenderkit.com) included right into Blender core add-ons. It provides free materials from online database through simple drag & drop.

The add-on also allows to upload user models and serve as library.

[image]