# How to Link or Append objects from another file?

Tags: linked-data

I've tried the instructions [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend) but cannot get linking and appending to work.  I have a file with just the default cube in it. Then I create a new file and go to File >> Link, and browse to the file and select the cube mesh but nothing shows up.  Same result for appending. Using Blender 2.79.   Thanks

Comment: Have you tried linking the actual Object, not just the Mesh?

Comment: That was the issue.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.  I was selecting the item to link/append from the list of Meshes, but needed to select the item from the list of Objects.

Comment: The meshes do go into your scene when you append them by the way - you can retrieve them by making a new mesh object and changing its mesh datablock to the one you just imported, which will probably have 0 users. This is also how you can change a mesh to share a datablock without the alt-d duplicate linked shortcut, which can be quite useful.