# How do you save materials that you create to use them later, in a different project?

Tags: export, import

Say you download a texture files from some website. Then, in blender, use those images in node editor to create a material.

​Or you just use existing nodes in Blender to create your own material.

How do you save that material to use it later in another project? I don't want to open up old projects, search for the materials and copy and paste its nodes it into my new projects. Is it possible to export those materials?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just save it as .blend and use the append function (File > Append and select the materials).

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/link_append.html