# How can I create a library of animations?

Tags: animation, blend-files, data-blocks

I want to store animations (just the animation data itself) so they can be recalled and reused in other projects.

How do I create such a library of purely animation data?

(For instance if I have some text animations that I like the feel of and wish to reuse)

I can see why you might flag this as possibly answered the question though the suggestions are not quite what I meant, I want a library that is visible to all projects without 'linking' akin to Photoshops presets.

In fact I wish this was the case with all data objects, materials textures etc.

**EDIT**
Please see the edit. I wasn't asking about linking files, but about libraries, so that animations appear as presets - this should not have been marked as duplicate especially in the light of this.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend

Comment: This should not have been marked as duplicate,  especially in the light of the update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Blender allows you to link or append.

Linking only creates a reference to the cross-referenced object.

Appending imports the cross-referenced object into your current file as a local copy.

Both are available through the File menu.

There's a great answer already on this site:

[How can I reuse existing materials, objects, etc from an existing .blend?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend)

**Presets**

So in response to your updated question I understand that you want something accessible from all projects without linking.

This is where add-ons come in.  There are loads of them out there and if you know (or are willing to learn) Python then you can roll your own add-on.  There are plenty of examples out there and here on how to go about this and also the source code for the included add-ons are available on git.blender.org.

Comment: Thanks but as mentioned this isn't quite what I am asking.

Comment: Blend files are libraries of object data, be it materials, meshes, textures or entire scenes that's just how blender works.  If this doesn't satisfy you then [upload a blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and be very specific about what you want to archive.  I think what you are getting at is an effects library, which you could write an add-on that pulls in data from a (you guessed it) blend file.  All roads lead to Rome.

Comment: It seems indeed they do, thanks Merlin. I am though surprised if this addon doesn't already exist, can check.

Comment: Have a look at https://blendermarket.com/products/ik-text-effects

Comment: Thanks, I can try the addon  route, does anyone know how I can contest this being marked as a duplicate?

Comment: It hasn't been, it would have a full banner under the question, it has only been commented that this this may be a duplicate.  There are no flags against it currently