# Is there an animation library addon for Blender?

Tags: animation, add-on

I'd like to save a character rig's animation data for reuse on the same rig in different scene files (eg walk cycles). In Maya I've used scripts such as PAIE or Studio Library. Does anything like these exist for Blender? Links below to clarify.

https://www.studiolibrary.com/

https://animationapprentice.blogspot.com/2015/01/the-free-paie-plugin-for-maya-how-it.html

Also, in case this is flagged as duplicate, this post doesn't answer this question - 
[How can I create a library of animations?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155766/how-can-i-create-a-library-of-animations)

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Can you explain *why* that link doesn't answer your question? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, unless I'm misunderstanding, that post and the links within it refer to reusing mostly mesh and material data. If you have a look at the links I posted it might be clearer what I'm after, it's a pretty standard ability to have in an animation production setup. I would imagine the Blender short films people had something like this but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: https://youtu.be/oXGKDG1BeW4 I hope this link can help you!