# how to merge and transfer files as one piece to other blender project

Tags: import, video, tracking, append

I want to add my robot model to the camera image with motion tracking, but I don't know how to add the model and rig files as one piece.
And the robot is walking on the stage. I have to add this as an animation, but how do I discard it? Is it possible ? 
https://ibb.co/CbtvMkz
https://ibb.co/nwH6wYP

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)