# How do I add to my scene a shader I downloaded?

Tags: shaders, append

I'm referencing this CC-0 shader:
https://www.cyn-prod.com/projects/wood.php

How do I add this to my scene?

I've tried "appending" but Blender drills down into the Blend file's directory structure.

I want to add wood texture to a kid's stool project.

Blender 2.82a

Comment: You're in the right place. Just go to the "Material" folder and select the material. Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to download is a full blown shader that is designed for wood. Unless you are making wood of all types, it seems like overkill to download a shader for it, as the principal shader included with blender more than enough. What you need is a wood **texture**.

Here is a texture website that I would recommend: https://cc0textures.com/list?q=wood&method=&type=&sort=Popular

Select the one you need, and hit download. **Unzipping the file will give you a folder.**

New go back to blender, select the object you want to give a wood texture, and press the shading tab on the top. **Create a new material for that object by pressing "new" on the top of shader editor**.

[image: default shader]

But first you need to **enable an add on called Node Wrangler** which will help you a lot while editing nodes. Go to "Edit" near the top, -> Preferences -> Add-Ons -> Search "node wrangler", and check the box.

Go back to the shading editor and select the big green box. **Press Ctrl-Shift-T. In the file picker it opened, find the folder you got from the texture website, open it, select all the files inside**, and press Principle Texture Setup on the bottom right. **Node wrangler will open up a lot of nodes automatically, and should look something like this.**

[image]

Aaaand.. that's about it. Now you can view this new texture by switching to LookDev or Render mode on the top right (make sure to go to the layout tab first).

Comment: Thanks Eric!  Great tips and it looks fantastic!   http://www.filedropper.com/screenshot11