# suddenly cant move pasted object (mesh), both move

Tags: objects, transforms

been ctrl c n v'ing my meshes to be more efficient when working. After pasting, the new identical mesh is in side the copied mesh (obviously). But now when I try and move the new mesh they both move. even when they are individually selected. Also while troubleshooting I also discovered if one of a new pasted object get inside one another they both become tethered and move as 1. as a hotfix I have been Duplicating the objects instead of c+v'ing. Did I hit a hotkey? is this a limitation? new to blender hope I explained well.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223993/how-do-i-prevent-duplicate-materials-when-copy-pasting

Comment: I will try to shed the curse of c+v