# Copy/Paste objects between files *without* parent?

Tags: objects, interface

A while ago, Blender changed the behavior of copy-paste between files, and I want to know if I can get the old behavior back. Basically, when I use the copy/paste function to copy an object from one instance of Blender, and paste it into another instance, it always brings that object's parent along with it. (Which sometimes can be something like a rigged character, with all of it dependencies)

Obviously one solution is to just unparent the object I want to copy, copy/paste it, then re-parent it or use undo to get it back. But this is kind of clunky.

In summary: Is there a way to just copy/paste an object between Blender instances without also pasting the object's parent?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223993/how-do-i-prevent-duplicate-materials-when-copy-pasting/223995#223995

Comment: I know there are other ways to do it, but it is often by far the quickest and easiest way to copy simple things from one file to another. The functionality is there, and worked one way before, and now it works differently. I'm just trying to find out how to get back the original behavior.