# Copying blender objects with an image texture into another blender object

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

I am copying one Blender object with an image texture into another Blender project. It does copy the body of the object but without an image texture. So I have empty block without an image.
Can someone help me to fix this?

Thank you,
Here is the link for object:
https://gofile.io/d/otleN1

Here is the link for the image:
https://gofile.io/d/cNpKkf

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/223995/19307

Comment: use the main menu *File > Append...* and choose the *Object* or *Collection* from the source blend file that you want to copy. For armatures also choose *Object* not *Armature* -- If an image is missing the object is displayed in pink color (your pink block). Use the main menu *File > External Data > Find Missing Files ...* and choose the directory where the image is to fix the broken reference. The image name must not have been changed.