Copying a single object (CTRL+C) and pasting it (CTRL+V) copy the whole scene, not a single object anymore
I was used to copying objects between projects or scenes by just copy pasting (selecting an object, pressing Ctrl + C, going to the other file or scenes, pressing Ctrl + V, and voila, one object from the original scene to the other scenes), but suddenly today that behavior changed.
Now when I copy an object from ExampleFile1.blend (Scene1) to ExampleFile2.blend (Scene1) it says One Object Copied, but when I paste it it created Scene1.001 on ExampleFile1.blend, with all X amount of objects that I had on ExampleFile2.blend, Scene1. Worst yet, when in ExampleBlend1.blend Scene1.001 I try to copy the object I wanted, upon pasting it Scene1.002 is created instead, with all the X amount of objects that there were on Scene1.001
From other answers I've tried different things to no avail. Append won't do because I use copy/paste for rapid prototyping, in the same way asset browser won't do. I jump from file to file, scene to scene, copying and mixing different assets in a fast workflow. I've a top of the line workstation (128gb ram, 32 core/64 threads, RTX4090, fast storage, etc.) and I did a clean install of Blender 4.1, I've not tried downgrading because I use custom plugins that I would have to port, and this was working just fine a few hours ago.

Did you try to use the Copy Attribute Menu addon? To me it's working fine in 4.1.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/223995/19307
