Difference between copy + paste and duplicate
I was watching a tutorial on blender as a beginner, and was curious what the difference between copy and paste, rather than duplicate was. Also, what's the difference between duplicate and duplicate linked? I know these answers have something to do with object data, but I'm not sure what that exactly means.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223993/how-do-i-prevent-duplicate-materials-when-copy-pasting/223995

The difference is:
Copy - Paste: creates a copy of object's data and materials. It can be used between different files.
Duplicate : Creates a copy of object's data, while materials are shared between copies. This behaviour can be changed in preferences:

Duplicate linked : Materials and object's data are shared between copies: if you edit one (move a vertex for example) - second will be changed as well.
