Copying objects error says "cannot change old file (file saved with @)"
Is there a way to fix this error?
Whenever I press Ctrl + C to copy, I get a message saying

"Cannot change old file (file saved with @)"

I’ve tried reinstalling Blender and even downloaded different versions, but the issue persists.


May I suggest to start with this post: Message "cannot-change-old-file-(file-saved-with-@)" trying to copy objects ?

AFAIK when you use the backup system Blender temporarily renames your file with an @ before adding .blend1, .blend2 etc. I think it means there was some form of corruption in the process of saving your file (eg power outage, or network disconnected)/ I suggest trying to save to a new file path with File > Save As

Blender clipboard works by saving to disk temporary files with the copied data. Maybe you have some locked or corrupted clipboard file, maybe it is being used by other process, or perhaps Blender doesn't have permissions to write to it. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/223995/19307 for more details. Maybe clear your temp files, or cleanup your temp folder.
